# Update version number in pom.xml using sed/awk

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed

I have a `pom.xml` in the following format:

```
<project>

<modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</project>
```

I want to increase the modelVersion number by +1 everytime by running a `sed`/`awk` command everytime,
for example to 2.0.0, 3.0.0, 4.0.0 and so on in the `pom.xml`.

So the expected output should be the following when i run the command

```
 <project>

<modelVersion>2.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</project>
```

If i run the same command again, the output should be

```
 <project>

<modelVersion>3.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</project>
```

Which one is preferred? How do I do it?

Comment: Imagine that you’re describing your problem to somebody who doesn’t already know what it is and who can’t read your mind, because that is exactly what you are doing.  Describe your situation and what you want to do.  You show a file that contains two different version numbers — which one do you want to change?  I’ll guess that you mean the `modelVersion`.  Do you ‘know’ in advance that the current version number is `4.0.0`, so you can ‘increase’ it with a `s/4/5/` command?  Or do you want a general solution that looks in the file and sees the current number?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  You say ‘increase’ — do you mean ‘add one’?  (Because adding 42 would also ‘increase’ the number.)  You say that your file is in the shown format, so I’ll assume that the `modelVersion` is guaranteed to be three integers separated by periods.  So what do you want to happen if the version number is something like ``4.0.1`` or ``4.2.17``? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … P.S. Functions that ‘increase’ an existing value (i.e., do arithmetic) are almost impossible in `sed` and are often straightforward in `awk`.

Comment: Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Given your updated example, this might be what you want, using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
awk 'match($0,/(.*<modelVersion>)([0-9]+)(.*)/,a) {$0=a[1] a[2]+1 a[3]} 1' file
```

To update the original file you could use `awk -i inplace '...' file` since the above requires GNU awk anyway and that supports `-i inplace`.

---

Original answer:
This might be what you want, using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
awk 'match($0,/(.*<modelVersion>)([0-9]+)(.*)/,a) {$0=a[1] (++cnt) a[3]} 1' file
```

The above is untested since your requirements aren't clear, we can't test incrementing a value with a sample input that only has 1 value in it and you didn't provide any expected output.

Comment: Fun fact: your answer and my answer were downvoted 2 seconds apart.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `awk` script:

```
awk '/<modelVersion>/ {
        temp = $0
        sub(/.*<modelVersion>/, "", temp)
        sub(/\..*/, "", temp)
        incremented = temp+1
        sub(temp, incremented)
    }
    {   print   }
    '
```

- Find the line that contains the `modelVersion`.
- Make a temporary copy of the entire line.
- Remove `<modelVersion>` (and anything preceding it)
  from the copy of the line, …
- and then remove the first **`.`** and everything after it. 
  This leaves the first component of the version number;
  e.g., `42.0.0` → `42`.
- Add one to that (e.g., → `43`).
- Then modify the input line to replace the current number
  with the increased number.

Run the `awk` command
with output to a file:

```
awk '(the above)' pom.xml > new.xml
```

check that the output is correct, and then

```
mv new.xml pom.xml
```